# How to set Textbox with only bottom border in MPDF

Tags: php, html, mpdf

[image]It works in html form but when we execute with mpdf library (pdf generator) then css will not work.

```
<input type="text" style="border:0px;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;" name="inputname" value="" title="Enter your name" />
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: <input type="text" style="border:0px;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;" name="inputname" value="" title="Enter your name" />

Comment: Try `border:none;` if it works for you.

Comment: No i have already tried it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only border color for entire border is supported for input elements in mPDF.

You could try setting the border to paper color (white) and set the border to surrounding div. Note that this only works when using [active forms](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/forms.html).

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'useActiveForms' => true,
]);

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<form><div style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
    <input type="text" style="border-color: white;" name="inputname" value="" title="Enter your name" />
</div></form>');
```

See https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html (search on page for `(type=PASSWORD| TEXT)`).